# Value Stored to 'valid' is never read

Tags: objective-c, boolean, dead-code

I have a validation method by which I analyse whether a particular variable passes a validation criteria.

Here's the code:

```
-(BOOL)validateFields{
    BOOL valid = FALSE;
    if (dateEntry != TRUE && saveOrderType != TRUE) {
        if (_editRequired==YES) {
            if ([[[editedTextField text] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]] isEqualToString:@""]) {
                valid = FALSE;
            } else {
                valid = TRUE;
            }
        } else {
            valid = TRUE;
        }
        if (_editRegEx) {
            NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression
                                      regularExpressionWithPattern:_editRegEx
                                      options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                      error:nil];
            if ([regex numberOfMatchesInString:[editedTextField text] options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [[editedTextField text] length])]==0) {
                valid=FALSE;
            } else {
                valid = TRUE;
            }
        } else {
            valid = TRUE;
        }

    } else {
        valid = TRUE;
    }
    return valid;
}
```

I'm getting 3 instances of `Value stored to 'valid' is never read` which is strange because eventually, it's returned at the end of the method.

I'm getting it on the first three instances of setting the variable, only on these three:

```
if (_editRequired==YES) {
    if (//checks if the field contains any characters) {
        valid = FALSE;
    } else {
        valid = TRUE;
    }
} else {
     valid = TRUE;
}
```

Can anybody help here?

Comment: I tried to reproduce it but it worked fine without any errors.Can you please send a sample project with the issue?

Comment: Same here. Can you replace this with the actual code: if (//checks if the field contains any characters) {

Comment: Sure, I'll update with the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `if (_editRequired==YES) {}` conditional  is completely overridden by the `if (_editRegEx) {}` conditional, so none of the assignments inside the former are ever used: `valid` is always reassigned in the second conditional.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that. I just removed the variable altogether and returned false for wherever it failed validation.

Answer (score 0):

You have this warning because you store an other value after this if/else.
Indeed just after that you have an other if (to test _editRegEx) and store a value in all cases (if and else). So your first if is not needed.